# Change ComboBox ItemsSource based on another ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I have two `ComboBoxes`A and B. First one is populated with a list of items.
I need to change the `ItemsSource` `Binding` of the B based on A's `SelectedItem`

Issue: When X is selected on A, B is not getting populated.

Please note that I'm **not** filtering the `ItemsSource`, it a complete change of binding. myItemSources are `ObservableCollections`

```
 <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxB">
    <ComboBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
           <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding myItemSource1}" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboBoxA}" Value="X">
                  <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding myItemSource2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968550/binding-a-list-with-another-list-with-wpf/28969440#28969440

Comment: @ AyyappanSubramanian My issue is different. I have over 5 SourceItems  want to bind to based on ComboBoxA selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of how to implement this kind of cascading ComboBoxes using the MVVM design pattern available here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/17/cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm/

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}" />

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"
          Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
```

---

```
public CustomObservableCollection<City> Cities {
  get;
  private set;
}

private Country _selectedCountry;
public Country SelectedCountry {
  get {
    return _selectedCountry;
  }
  set {
    _selectedCountry = value;
    this.Cities.Repopulate(_selectedCountry.Cities);
  }
}
...
}
```