# Wpf - Binding one gridcontrol selected row data and populate it in another gridcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one gridcontrol with various fields which i havent mentioned in my code

```
<dxg:GridControl   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="300"  VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="grid1"  AutoPopulateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}"    >
                    <dxg:GridControl.View >
                        <dxg:TableView x:Name="TableView1" />
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                .   
                .   
                .   
                .
```

I have another grid control on the same page with various fields

```
<dxg:GridControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250"  VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="grid2"  AutoPopulateColumns="False"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName="TableView1" ,path=Collection2.FocusedRow}"    >
                    <dxg:GridControl.View >
                        <dxg:TableView x:Name="TableView2"  />
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                .   
                .   
                .   
                .
```

now collection1 **Id** is primary key and collection2 **colID** is foreign key both are having relationship with each other

Scenario here is if i select a row in grid1 all the corresponding records must be displayed in grid 2

```
 public class myCollection: BindingList<orders>
{
     public DataContext dc;

    public myCollection(IList<orders> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        orders deleteItem = this.Items[index];

        if (Dc.Order != null)
        {
            Dc.Order.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteItem);
        }
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

}
```

> My generic class for orders and generic class for master is the same

Comment: Is Collection2 a property of the type of objects in the Collection1?

Comment: Collection2 is EntityRef object in collection1

Comment: It needs to be an IEnumerable for you to be able to bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to it. Using auto-generated Entity Framework classes in a WPF application is rarely useful in real-world scenarios. You should create your own classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I speak in terms of XAML properties, here you want to update ItemsSource property of 2nd Datagrid on basis of SelectedItem property of 1st Datagrid.

To achieve this, add a new property "SelectedItemDg1" in ViewModel which will hold the selection of 1st DataGrid. In Setter of this "SelectedItemDg1" property, set Collection2 as per your need.

Make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and use ObservableCollection type for both the collections.

Following is the code sample for same :

> Model Classes:

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public List<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

> ViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CountriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        StateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        LoadData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Country> _CountriesCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Country> CountriesCollection
    {
        get { return _CountriesCollection; }
        set
        {
            _CountriesCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CountriesCollection");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<State> _StatesCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<State> StateCollection
    {
        get { return _StatesCollection; }
        set
        {
            _StatesCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StateCollection");
        }
    }

    private Country _SelectedCountry;

    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get { return _SelectedCountry; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCountry = value;
            if (_SelectedCountry != null && _SelectedCountry.States != null)
            {
                StateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>(_SelectedCountry.States);
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        if (CountriesCollection != null)
        {
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 1,
                CountryName = "India",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 1, StateName = "Gujarat"},
                                    new State { StateId = 2, StateName = "Punjab"},
                                    new State { StateId = 3, StateName = "Maharastra"}
                            }
            });
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 2,
                CountryName = "Chine",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 4, StateName = "Chine_State1"},
                                    new State { StateId = 5, StateName = "Chine_State2"},
                                    new State { StateId = 6, StateName = "Chine_State3"}
                            }
            });
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 3,
                CountryName = "japan",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 7, StateName = "Japan_State1"},
                                    new State { StateId = 8, StateName = "Japan_State2"},
                                    new State { StateId = 9, StateName = "Japan_State3"}
                            }
            });
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

}
```

> XALM :

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              Height="300" Width="300" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesCollection}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}">

    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              Height="300" Width="300" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCountry.States}">

    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Here I have AutoGenerateColumns property of DataGrid but you have to change it as per your requirement.

I hope this sample code will make things easy to understand for you.

Comment: i have L2S with INotifyPropertyChanged and IBindingList. YES thats exactly what i need

Comment: I would like to know more because  i am new to this.

Comment: I see your problem is quite similar to the classical example of Country and State combo box. Here is the link for one such example. I think you can understand better from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050501/change-combobox-itemssource-based-on-another-combobox-selection

Comment: the link you have provided works fine for a selectedItem but i couldnt achieve the same for a focusedrow in TableView

Comment: What you mean by "focusedrow"? Are you using some third party controls?

Comment: no my point is i have to deal with FocusedRow property of master  and 
 then populate the detail as per focused data in master .yes i am using Devexpress Grid. do check my question i have updated it

Comment: Yes you have to deal with FocusedRow property and that you will do by Binding Selecteditem property of DataGrid. On setter of  this property, you will update the Collection2. I am preparing simple code sample for you. Will post it in while. Meanwhile you can try playing with SelectedItem :)

Comment: Thank you It Worked :0 #bhai

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. And I hope you learned few things from my post :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way I found to do this sort of master-details binding on collections is to wrap `ObservableCollection` in a class, expose its `ListCollectionView` and bind your `ItemsSource` to it, like below (it has some extra code that is used to simplify xml serialization):

```
public class ViewableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ListCollectionView _View;

    public ViewableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items) { }

    public ViewableCollection()
        : base() { }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ListCollectionView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (_View == null)
            {
                _View = new ListCollectionView(this);
                _View.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(InnerView_CurrentChanged);
            }
            return _View;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public T CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)this.View.CurrentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.View.MoveCurrentTo(value);
        }
    }

    private void InnerView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentItem"));
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, (IList)range.ToList()));
    }

    public void ReplaceItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {

        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Remove(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, (IList)range.ToList()));
    }

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        IList old = this.Items.ToList();
        base.Items.Clear();
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, old));
    }

    public void CallCollectionChaged()
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator List<T>(ViewableCollection<T> o)
    {
        return o == null ? default(List<T>) : o.ToList();
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator ViewableCollection<T>(List<T> o)
    {
        return o == default(List<T>) || o == null ? new ViewableCollection<T>() : new ViewableCollection<T>(o);
    }
}
```

Then in your `ViewModel` (Remember to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I use a nuget package `Fody.PropertyChanged` to automatically implement it on properties):

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ViewableCollection<MySecondViewModel> Collection1 { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Collection1 = new ViewableCollection<MySecondViewModel>();
    }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MySecondViewModel
{ 
    public string MyColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn2 { get; set; }
    public ViewableCollection<MyThirdViewModel> Collection2 { get; set; }

    public MySecondViewModel()
    {
        this.Collection1 = new ViewableCollection<MyThirdViewModel>();
    }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyThirdViewModel
{ 
    public string MyColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn2 { get; set; }
}

//...
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

Then, keeping your grids synchronized is as simple as this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1.View, Mode=OneWay}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1.CurrentItem.Collection2.View, Mode=OneWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

For example binding to a `Column1` property in currently selected item in currently selected `Collection2` will be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Collection1.CurrentItem.Collection2.CurrentItem.Column1}" />
```

Also, you can manage selection in your code behind, for example:

```
Collection1.CurrentItem=null;
```

will clear the selection on the collection.

You can also sort (and filter and group) the `ViewableCollection` from code behind like this:

```
Collection1.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Column1",ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Just remember that you should't replace the whole `ViewableCollection` after it's been instantiated, just add/remove items from it (for this purpose there is the method `AddRange` and `ReplaceItems` for adding/replacing items in bulk without rising `CollectionChanged` events unnecessarily)

Comment: Check my question i have updated it abit , i have Ibindnglist implemented in my collection.